# trying to get data to be chart ready

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given:  [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58fb3/3)

```
TopProducts table
------------------
Name, Count, Choice
WidgetA, 3, Pick1
WidgetB, 1, Pick1
WidgetB, 1, Pick2
WidgetC, 1, Pick2
WidgetA, 1, Pick3
WidgetD, 3, Pick3
```

I'd like to get the data ready for charting if possible. The chart will have multiple series based on choices. I imagine the data should look like the following:

```
WidgetA, 3, Pick1
WidgetB, 1, Pick1
WidgetC, null, Pick1
WidgetD, null, Pick1
WidgetA, null, Pick2
WidgetB, 1, Pick2
WidgetC, 1, Pick2
WidgetD, null, Pick2
WidgetA, 1, Pick3
WidgetB, null, Pick3
WidgetC, null, Pick3
WidgetD, 3, Pick3
```

Comment: What type of chart are you making? What tool do you plan to use to create a chart? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the cartesian product of unique values on columns: `Name` and `Choice` to be able to get all the possible combinations.

The result of the cartesian product will then be joined using `LEFT JOIN` by table to get the value of the `Count`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        b.Name,
        c.Count,
        a.Choice
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Choice FROM TopProducts) a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM TopProducts) b
        LEFT JOIN TopProducts c
            ON  a.Choice = c.Choice
                AND b.name = c.Name
ORDER   BY a.Choice, b.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86bef/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦════════╦════════╗
║  NAME   ║ COUNT  ║ CHOICE ║
╠═════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ WidgetA ║ 3      ║ Pick1  ║
║ WidgetB ║ 1      ║ Pick1  ║
║ WidgetC ║ (null) ║ Pick1  ║
║ WidgetD ║ (null) ║ Pick1  ║
║ WidgetA ║ (null) ║ Pick2  ║
║ WidgetB ║ 1      ║ Pick2  ║
║ WidgetC ║ 1      ║ Pick2  ║
║ WidgetD ║ (null) ║ Pick2  ║
║ WidgetA ║ 1      ║ Pick3  ║
║ WidgetB ║ (null) ║ Pick3  ║
║ WidgetC ║ (null) ║ Pick3  ║
║ WidgetD ║ 3      ║ Pick3  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86bef/7 - So if I wanted to pivot the data would I add-on to what you gave? For example, have the names on the side and the choices along the top